# How to set brushes to filtered range with dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I've created [this](http://bourlo.net/work/haags-kind/) visualization and would like to use predefined filters in the explanation text. I created a link where the filter is applied on a barchart like so:

```
<a href="javascript:filterAge([13,14,15])">Filter</a>
```

The filterAge function is:

```
function filterAge(filters) {
  dc.filterAll();
  for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    ageChart.filter(filters[i]); 
  }
  dc.redrawAll();
}
```

The filter works ok, however the brushes in the Age chart are not set accordingly. So for a user it is hard to tell what exactly has been filtered.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350893/how-to-set-d3-brush-extent-right) question but did not manage to apply this to the dc.js way of working. [Another](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/249) question seems in the same direction but lacks a thorough answer.

Comment: I am assuming that your chart has a quantitative, not ordinal x scale - the brushes work quite differently in each case in dc.js. If it were ordinal, this should work. If quantitative, this is a dupe as flagged above.

Comment: Hmm, how did SO close this as duplicate without providing a link? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29041518/676195

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we don't have enough reviewers to get questions marked as duplicate, I'll spell this out.

dc.js treats filtering completely differently for quantitative scales, so you can't use the code above, which is for ordinal scales.

Try using a [ranged filter object](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dcfiltersrangedfilterlow-high) instead:

```
<a href="javascript:filterAge(13,16)">Filter</a>

function filterAge(low, high) {
  dc.filterAll();
  ageChart.filter(dc.filters.RangedFilter(low, high));
  dc.redrawAll();
}
```