# D3.js v3 to v4 Brush changes

Tags: d3.js

I'm looking to migrate from d3v3 to d3v4.
In particular i'm having difficulties in migrating brushes.

Can someone please have a look at below link and let me know the changes?
http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/ddff7cd0b1220bc68a58

Some changes i have identified:

d3.time.format -> d3.timeFormat

d3.time.scale -> d3.scaleTime

Facing issues in migrating:

d3.svg.brush -> d3.brushX

Thanks & Regards,

Naishav

Comment: This link will help you to migrate from d3v3 to d3v4 : https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems rather strange to abuse the `d3.brush` like that when you can code this so much more straightforward with regular events:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
      body {
      background-color: #393939;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
    
    p {
      color: white;
      margin: 50px;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #4FDEF2;
    }
    
    .axis {
      fill: gray;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .axis .halo {
      stroke: gray;
      stroke-width: 4px;
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }
    
    .handle path {
      stroke: white;
      stroke-width: 3px;
      stroke-linecap: round;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .handle text {
      fill: white;
      text-align: center;
      font
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // parameters
    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 300 - margin.bottom - margin.top;


    // scale function
    var timeScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([new Date('2012-01-02'), new Date('2013-01-01')])
      .range([0, width])
      .clamp(true);

    var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%b %d");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      // classic transform to position g
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      

    svg.append("rect")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("cursor", "crosshair")
      .on("mousedown", function(){
        updatePos(this);
      })
      .on("mousemove", function(){
        if (d3.event.which === 1){
          updatePos(this);
        }
      });

    function updatePos(elem){
      var xPos = d3.mouse(elem)[0];
      handle.attr('transform', 'translate(' + xPos + ",0)");
      text.text(formatDate(timeScale.invert(xPos)));
    }

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      // put in middle of screen
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
      // inroduce axis
      .call(d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(timeScale)
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
          return formatDate(d);
        })
        .tickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(12)
        .tickValues([timeScale.domain()[0], timeScale.domain()[1]]))
      .select(".domain")
      .select(function() {
        console.log(this);
        return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
      })
      .attr("class", "halo");

    var handle = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "handle")
      
    handle.append("path")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
      .attr("d", "M 0 -20 V 20")

    var text = handle.append('text')
      .text(formatDate(timeScale.domain()[0]))
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-18) + " ," + (height / 2 - 25) + ")");

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing much simple way to do it. d3.brush seems to be much more complex in d3v4.

Comment: @AlexanderShutov, I fixed the snippet.

Comment: I also don't like black boxes, but in this case D3 brush also handles Touch events and some Key presses (eg. when you hold ALT key, you can change selection in both directions) https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js

Answer (score 43):

#### Quick guide for migrating `d3-brush` from D3 v3 to D3 v4 *(example for brushX)*

1. Replace `d3.svg.brush()` with `d3.brushX()`.
2. Rename `brushstart` event to `start`, `brushend` to `end`.
3. Don't pass scale to `.x(xScale)`, this method is now missing. Pass brush borders as `.extent([[xScale.range()[0], 0], [xScale.range()[1], brushHeight]])`.
4. In event handler you can get selection as `d3.event.selection`, for getting selected values use `d3.event.selection.map(xScale.invert)`.
5. To setup selection do `.move(brushContainer, selectedDomain.map(xScale))`. To clear selection do `.move(brushContainer, null)`. Note that this will fire event handlers.
6. `.empty()` method is now missing, use `d3.event.selection === null`.
7. Update your CSS, `.extent` is now `.selection`, `.resize` is `.handle` and became a `rect` instead of `g` containing `rect`.